# Wallpaper settings for changing multiple-monitor setups

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

[image: different setups]

Since a while I have to switch between different screen setups on a daily basis with my laptop. Luckily Windows 7 is smart enough to recognize which screen is connected, and adjusts the position, and which screein is the primary screen accordingly.

However, one thing which does not change correctly is the wallpaper. I have 3 wallpaper files in 3 different resolutions, corresponding to the different screens. Is there a way to let this change automatically so that each screen always picks the wallpaper with the right resolution?

I know I can make different profiles with for instance UltraMon, for the different monitor setups. However, since I swap at least once a day, I do not want to select a different profile each time. Can this be automated?

Comment: From past experience, although not with 7, I would have to say you have to manually swap it each time.